# Javascript shows Invalid date

Tags: javascript

If I create date like this everything works fine: `var someDate = new Date("2013,2,1");`.

But I want to add time to this date also. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date <- Here was suggested like this: `var someDate = new Date("2013,2,1,1,20");`
But it shows `Invalid date`! How can I create date with thime?

Comment: Use var someDate = new Date(2013,2,1,1,20); instead of var someDate = new Date("2013,2,1")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date` constructor does not get as an argument string with values. Try with:

```
var someDate = new Date(2013,2,1,1,20);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a string parameter separated by a comma (,) you can try

```
new Date("2013,03,15,1:20");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without `"`

```
new Date(2013,2,1,1,20)
```